# Dynamically change image on UITabBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I can't seem to make the image change when I click on the tab-item.  It changes when I click some other tab-item.  But changes back when pressed.

The text changes right away and is permanent.

```
Setup Method
...

    UITabBar *myTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 10)];
    myTabBar.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:myTabBar];
    [myTabBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    NSMutableArray *tabBarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item1" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-25.png"] tag:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item2" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-25.png"] tag:1 ];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item3" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-25.png"] tag:2 ];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item4" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-25.png"] tag:3 ];

    [tabBarItems addObject:tabBarItem1];
    [tabBarItems addObject:tabBarItem2];
    [tabBarItems addObject:tabBarItem3];
    [tabBarItems addObject:tabBarItem4];


    myTabBar.items = tabBarItems;
    myTabBar.selectedItem = [tabBarItems objectAtIndex:0];
}

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    NSInteger selectedTag = tabBar.selectedItem.tag;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)selectedTag);
    if (selectedTag == 0) {
        [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-32.png"]];
        [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"B Item 1"];
    } else if(selectedTag == 1) {
        [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-32.png"]];
        [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"B Item 2"];
    } else if(selectedTag == 2) {
        [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-32.png"]];
        [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:@"B Item 3"];
    } else if(selectedTag == 3) {
        [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-32.png"]];
        [[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setTitle:@"B Item 4"];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that tab bar items have a `selectedImage` property?

Comment: @ jcaron,  I am now... thx